# Musgrave texture colour issue

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image: Musgrave-texture]
[image]
Does anyone know why there is no colour option for the muskgrave texture?

Comment: Musgrave is a black and white texture, what would you expect from a color output?

Comment: You can plug its Fac output into a color ramp, and set all the colors you need.